# Extract CSV file with format in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, format, export-to-csv

I want to extract the CSV file from SQL Server and I manage to do that with the following code:

```
DECLARE @bcpCommand1 VARCHAR(2000) 
SET @bcpCommand1 = 'bcp " SELECT * from ##tblUser " queryout' 
SET @bcpCommand1 = @bcpCommand1 + ' C:\OutPut\CSV\My_Output.csv -c -w -T -S197.1.1.1 -Umyuser -Pmypwd","-CRAW'  

EXEC CPS..xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand1
```

But the problem is ...

1. The big integer values are automatically coverted to scientific notation in CSV. Instead of this I want to display all the digits as it is.
2. I want to display the date as '01-Dec-2015 11:20 AM'.
3. If any data contains a comma, then the data is split to the next column. For example name is "mohan,Raj" then in the `.csv` data `Mohan` is in one column and `raj` in another column. How to avoid that?
4. Is there any way extract `.csv` using format file. How to do that?

Is there any way to do that? Please help me on this and post the code for that.

Comment: Are you going to import the data in `SQL Server` database or other? If you are going to import the data back in `SQL Server` database it should handle the conversion automatically. If you want to store the data in a specific format, just use `CONVERT` in your `T-SQL statement`. If you have commas in the values, using comma is bad - you should use other character - for example, some not printable character - you can use sequence of characters, too. If you should use `CSV` you can replace the values which have commas with other character (Cyrillic comma  `,`) and when importing replace it back.

Answer (score 0):

The BCP is used to copy whatever from a table to csv or txt or xml format.
If you want to get the comma separated values in one column as multiple column in csv. Then you have to modify your temp table accordingly.

2. I want to display the date as '01-Dec-2015 11:20 AM'.
   There is not direct conversion to your exact format
   you can use this code to do the same

   ```
    SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), GETDATE(), 106), ' ', '-') +' '+STUFF(RIGHT( CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),100 ) ,7), 6, 0, ' ')
   ```

4) Is there any way extract csv using format file.How to do that?

**sqlcmd -S MyServer -d myDB -E -Q "select col1, col2, col3 from SomeTable" 
               -o "MyData.csv" -h-1 -s"," -w 700**

```
   -h-1 removes column name headers from the result
   -s"," sets the column seperator to , 
   -w 700 sets the row width to 700 chars 
(this will need to be as wide as the longest row or it will wrap to the next line)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer on your 4th question (and it helps with questions 1 and 2). To load csv-data on server you can use:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
SELECT a.* FROM OPENROWSET( BULK 'D:\our.csv', FORMATFILE = 'D:\our.fmt') AS a;
```

The sample of our.fmt (it's file that describes the fields in csv)

```
9.0
4
1  SQLCHAR  0  50 ";"        1  Field1                SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
2  SQLCHAR  0  50 ";"        2  Field2                SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
3  SQLCHAR  0  50 ";"        3  Field3                SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
4  SQLCHAR  0  500 "\r\n"      4  Field4        SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
```

You can find description of `*.fmt` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190393.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).